# Converting equation of a plane to a different form

Tags: vectors

How can i convert the equation of a plane in the form:

$2x + 3y + 4z = 48$ to

$r = a + λb + μc$,

where a is a vector, b and c are vectors of the form $p\:\bf{i}+q\:\bf{j}$ and $s\:\bf{i} + t\:\bf{k}$ respectively, where $p$, $q$, $s$ and $t$ are integers.

Can some one please explain?

Comment: why are there $5$ variables $p, q, \cdots, t$ to describe a plane in three dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $2x+3y+4z=48$ as $\displaystyle\frac{x}{24}+\frac{y}{16}+\frac{z}{12}=1$.

Now you can easily determine the intersection points of the plane with the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes:
$$(24,0,0)\;(0,16,0)\text{ and }(0,0,12)$$

Two possible direction vectors of the plane are $(-24,16,0)$ and $(-24,0,12)$

The parameter equation of the plane is then
\begin{equation}
(x,y,z)=(24,0,0)+\lambda(-24,16,0)+\mu(-24,0,12)
\end{equation}

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

$r=a+\lambda b +\mu c$ is the vector form of the equation of a plane. $a$ is a point on the plane. $b,c$ are direction vectors of the plane.

You want your $a$ to be in the form of $(p,0,0)$. So plug $(0,0)$ into your original equation, you can get $(24,0,0)$ for $a$.

The $b$ is a vector in the form of $(q,r,0)$ and is orthogonal to the normal vector $(2,3,4)$. So for example, $(-3,2,0)$ would work. Because their dot product is $0$.

If you see the pattern, you should be able to find $c$ in the similar way.